# Copying MYSQL backup to another server

Tags: mysql, automation, ssh, cron

I'm new to SSH. How to copy a .gz file from one server to another using SSH?

I'm using cron to backup mysql databases and want to also automate the process of copying the .gz files a different web host.

Any information on the limit of file size that can be copied would also be great. The backup file size range from 100 MB to few GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Remote File Copy (`rcp`) or `ftp`.
There's no size limit.

Edit: [Secure File Copy](http://www-hep2.fzu.cz/computing/adm/scp.html) (`scp`) is the best option.
Use it like this:

```
scp user1@host1:/home/sourcefile user2@host2:/dest/directory/
```